# How to run Jest unit tests in Angular when using automapper-ts

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have swapped out karma/jasmine in my Angular 7 TypeScript project for Jest using the [Jest Schematic](https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic) from briebug. Everything seems to be working well apart from I cannot get it to locate AutomapperJS which is used in the [automapper-ts library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-ts).

Automapper-ts is installed and working fine in my application and runs fine under karma/jasmine but gives me the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run
ReferenceError: AutoMapperJs is not defined
```

I have tried to add  import 'automapper-ts'; at the top of my setup-jest.ts file but with no luck.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I don't want to speak for `automapper-ts` but because of how outdated `automapper-ts` is, I created `@nartc/automapper`: https://github.com/nartc/mapper

Comment: No I didnt, i backed out of using automapper-ts and found it quicker to just manually map for what I needed. I will check out your mapper, so thanks for the heads up.